# Java Regex to get Data between curly brackets

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regular expression to match the text between curly brackets.

```
{one}{two}{three}
```

I want each of these as separate groups, as `one` `two` `three` separately.

I tried `Pattern.compile("\\{.*?\\}");` which removes only first and last curly brackets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a capturing group `( )` around what you want to capture.

To just match and capture what is between your curly brackets.

```
String s  = "{one}{two}{three}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Output

```
one
two
three
```

If you want three specific match groups...

```
String s  = "{one}{two}{three}";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([^}]*)\\}\\{([^}]*)\\}\\{([^}]*)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1) + ", " + m.group(2) + ", " + m.group(3));
}
```

Output

```
one, two, three
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want 3 groups, your pattern needs 3 groups.

```
"\\{([^}]*)\\}\\{([^}]*)\\}\\{([^}]*)\\}"
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(The middle part is the same as the left and right).