# Regex to Search keywords between {{ and }} in Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds

What will be the Regex to Search keywords between `{{` and `}}` in Java.

Example `String = "kksdkjhsd {{one}} sdkjhsdjksd {{two}}"`
I want `output = ["one","two"];`

I have already tried approach suggested in [Java Regex to get Data between curly brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229887/java-regex-to-get-data-between-curly-brackets).

It works fine with single braces but I couldn't extend it for double flower(`{{ }}`) braces

Comment: What problems did you have with extending `\{([^}]*)\}` to `\{\{([^}]*)\}\}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static final String REGEX_START = Pattern.quote("{{");
    public static final String REGEX_END = Pattern.quote("}}");
    public static final Pattern PATTERN = Pattern.compile(REGEX_START + "(.*?)" + REGEX_END);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "kksdkjhsd {{one}} sdkjhsdjksd {{two}}";
        List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<>();

        Matcher matcher = PATTERN.matcher(input);

        // Check for matches
        while (matcher.find()) {
            keywords.add(matcher.group(1)); // Group one is necessary because of the brackets in the pattern
        }

        // Print
        keywords.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

This will give you everything between `{{` and `}}` so you will get a result like this:

```
one
two
```

Answer (score 5):

This code should fit your requirement:

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{([^\\}]*)\\}\\}").matcher(word);

while (m.find()){
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

This regular expression takes all the text within the `{{` `}}` which is not a `}` character. This regex doesn't handle case limit like `{{{}}}`, in this case returns `{` because only the first two `{{` are matched.

If you need a regular expression that match also single curly brackets within the scope we need a more complex solution.

Another thing, using the character class `([^\\}]*)` makes the regex much more efficient than `(.*?)`, because it will stop the search at first character that not is a closed curly brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the regexp `[{][{].*?[}][}]`. It uses the reluctant quantifier `*?`, which matches zero or more characters, but in a non-greedy fashion, so, once it starts matching `{{` it will stop at the first `}}` it encounters, rather than going all the way to the end of the string and matching the *last* `}}`.

As a fun little extra, it can match things like `hey {{ how {} are }} you`, and produce `how {} are` as the output, whereas regexps based on `[^}]*` can't.